# Android error: W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 384x0 dp

Tags: java, android, xml

Others too have this issue, but mine is unique (I think) in that this error only occurs when I open the keyboard within the app like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkXsS.png). It does not happen when the keyboard is not opened.

Again, the error is:

```
W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 384x0 dp.
```

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter your Number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="25"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:maxLength="31"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/from"
    android:text="@string/from"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:entries="@array/spinner_entries1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/to"
    android:text="@string/to"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@null"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:entries="@array/spinner_entries2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/output"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="25"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:maxLength="31"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:onClick="convert"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I go about fixing this?

EDIT: I wouldn't bother fixing this, because the ad returns back to normal when the keyboard goes away, BUT Views flicker when the keyboard 'touches' a view.

Comment: Once the keyboard is open, there isn't enough room remaining for the ad. Looking at the image clearly shows that is the case. There's no room left. What part of that is unclear to you? How is this *unique* to you? There's no screen real estate available in which to show the ad.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes. There isn't enough room to show the ad. How do I go about fixing this when the keyboard is open? It is unique as in no one else has asked this question.

Comment: @KenWhite See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

to `AndroidManifest.xml` under `<activity</>`

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8682529/6173191)